# On VSC, can I copy/paste folded codes and keep them folded?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, if I fold code

```
div
something here
/div
```

into

```
div...
/div
```

And copy and paste the folded code, the result appears as unfolded code lines.
Is there any way to keep them folded when paste? It looks like it is default on pycharm. :(

Comment: It is beyond annoying. It seems it can be discussed now here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16082

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way:

**Step1:** Open your code in vscode

**Step2:** `Cmd + Shift + P` (Mac) or `Ctrl+Shift+P` (Windows) to open `Command Palette`, search and select `Fold All`

**Step3:** Toolbar -> Selection -> Column Selection Mode

**Step4:** Column select all the code, copy and paste, done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, see [[folding] retain folded state on copy/paste](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16082)
.  I do not think it is language-specific but happens to all languages.

It is on the Backlog since 2016, and not many votes...  so upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a keybinding that pastes and then folds all blocks, it's a workaround so make sure that the block that you're pasting in aren't foldable, then make it foldable again once you pasted all your code.

Edit your `keybindings.json`, adding the following code:

```
{
"key": "ctrl+alt+v",
"command": "runCommands",
"args": {
  "commands": ["editor.action.clipboardPasteAction", "editor.foldAll"]
}}
```